# Puedo descargar vue-material sin usar npm y cargarlo local

Tags: vue.js, material-design

quiero hacer una aplicacion web con vue-material pero no puedo instalar por npm porque uso un proxy empresarial y no logro configurar el proxy en el cmd. 
Puedo descargar el codigo fuente de github y usarlo en mi proyecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes usar es un CDN como [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com) o [jsdelivr](https://jsdelivr.com).

Y puedes utilizar esos complementos así:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-material"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Editado**

Aunque es mas recomendable jsdelivr, ya que unpkg tiende a ser mas lento